# Problem replacing string within a list thats is attribute to an object within a loop

Tags: c#

I have a class `Plott`. One of the attributes is a list with header names called `Headers`. The list stores the names of all the columns within the plot.

I need to loop through these objects (plt which are in a List) and find any occurrences of headers containing the string `"aaa"` and replace it with the string `"bbb"`.

I successfully loop through and find these headers within these objects. I can also define a new string which replaces `"aaa"` with `"bbb"` but when I try to assignee the new string i.e that index of the List to that object it gives an error regarding that the set has changed and the loop can't continue (the error message is not in English so I wont post it here)

```
foreach (Plott obj in plt) {
    int c = 0;
    foreach (String s in obj.Headers)
    { 
        if (s.Contains("aaa"))
        {
            string newstr;
            newstr = s.Replace("aaa", "bbb");
            obj.Headers[c] = newstr;
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're changing the list you are looping thru. the error message is spot on.

Comment: yes but I'm not changing the number of items in the list? I'm just altering an entry.

Comment: 'just' altering thing being looped thru...find another way - hint: -grab the indexes for items being changed first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you retrieve in a foreach loop is a readonly copy of the element in the collection, so you can't modify it.

If you want to do this then you need  to use a simple for loop

```
for (int ind = 0; ind < plt.Count(); ind++)
{  
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know. Now I wont make this mistake again.

Comment: Note that only the inner loop over *Headers* needs to be changed to a `for` loop the outer loop over *plt* can still be a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the whole list.

```
obj.Headers = obj.Headers.Select( x => x.Replace("aaa","bbb") ).ToList();
```

Comment: This will only work if obj.Headers has a public setter